How to mass-reset the protected flag in classic MacOS
I have a library of 123k Mac (mostly System 7 and older) related files in 32k folders on a 40GiB volume on a file server running Novell Netware 3.12 from 1993 on VMware ESXi. Netware has excellent AFP support (for AppleTalk only) but I want to move away from it for reasons not relevant to my question.
I've used Dantz Retrospect backup software on an old System 7 Mac to copy those files over to another volume (Netatalk 2, Linux). Retrospect offers to compare the copy for errors and I found that it fails to set the time stamp of the copy to the original file's time stamp for all files which have the "protected" flag set.
This affects hundreds, if not thousands of files, so I'm searching for a way to automatically unset this flag for the whole volume. Spending hours to click through dozens of nested folders, open Cmd-I manually for each affected file, unselect "protect" and close the info window again is not an option. 
I have tried to use a DOS PC to run the DOS command flag . Rw sub at the volume level, but this exits with a permission denied error after a while. The last name is a generated DOS compatible name with "unusual" characters in it. I guess DOS chokes over those file's or folder's special "Mac" characters.
What other options can you recommend to automatically unset the "protect" flag for affected files on such a huge file base in an automatic manner?

The easiest way I've found out is to use the FileTyper package. Contained within is a tool to create a so called Autotyper. The UI presented allow to precisely specify to

select only locked ("protected") files,
remove the locked ("protected") flag.

All other attributes are set to be ignored/left as is by default.
After saving the Autotyper application, I gave it 64M of memory, just to be sure.
Running the Autotyper went surprisingly fast, just a couple of minutes.
